# Whose avatar was Sri akkalkot swami?

Tags: avatars, saint

He was a famous saint from maharastrian bhakti movement. He used to live in akkalkot which is a pilgrim place now

Whose avatar was he ?

Comment: Who else are left behind? Going like this you can easily cross the 100 Qs mark within no time :P

Comment: As per Guru-Charitra based on life of NrSimha Saraswati. He is avatar of Lord Dattatreya; son of sage Atri.

Comment: Why the Downvote. ?? There is absolutely no need to Downvote , as this question is perfectly fine. Shree Swami Samartha is very well known Saint in Many states of India.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes you are right downvote not necessary.

Comment: @Rickross - Haha and there is no objectionable thing in the question also. Actually Swami Samarth is widely worshipped in Maharashtra ,Karnataka as avatara of Shree Dattatreya.

Answer (score 4):

[**Sri Swami Samarth**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Samarth)  Maharaj of Akkalkot is considered as an **incarnation of Shree Dattatreya.** In this incarnation  [**Shree Narasimha Saraswati**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimha_Saraswati) had also personally manifested.

---

This is described in a book  [**Guru Charitra**](http://swamisamarth.com/guru-charitra/)   – **Complete Biography of Shree Akkalkot Niwasi Swami Samarth Maharaj**

> Sri Swami Samarth Maharaj was the complete incarnation of Lord
>   Dattatrey Himself. In this incarnation of Sri Swami Samarth, Sri
>   Narsinha Saraswati had also personally manifested. The manifestation
>   of Lord Dattatrey, Sri Narsinha Saraswati and Sri Swami Samarth though
>   taken separately, are but one and the same. They are the three forms
>   of the same manifestation of Lord Dattatrey himself. **Page No.64**

---

> In the year 14th or 15th century, there was a serious calamity due to
>   Muslim invasion in India. During this transitory period Sri Narsinha
>   Saraswati, by his actions advised Brahmins to carry on the duties as
>   prescribed in the Shastras . Sriguru gave relief to the lowest
>   category of the people from their misery and directed them towards the
>   devotional path. He even enlightened Muslims and the rulers of their
>   period. Later on in the 18th century manifested himself in the form of
>   Sri Swami Samarth. This was the transition period of British invasion
>   in India, and hence Sri Swami Samarth manifested himself in the most
>   unusual form of an accomplished ascetic. Therefore, during the period
>   of his incarnation he exerted more importance on good conduct and
>   devotion than the duties in regard to the four castes and four stages
>   of life. **Page No -65**

The role of this incarnation was to morally uplift all classes of people especially those who are at lower level. 18 th century  was the transition period of British invasion . And at that time Shree Narsinha Saraswati manifested himself as Swami Samartha to guide the people on good conduct.

The book describes many miracles and various other  simlar instances where his devotees , including royal families accepted his divinity. And from his own teachings and sayings his devotees came to know about this incarnation.

---

[image]

Comment: Nice find, BTW how to confirm from physical signs if one is avatara or not? Are these avataras all endowed with long arms for example (Ajanu lambita vahu)?

Comment: No unfortunately unlike other avataras it's not directly possible to see the avatars in the original form. As said in Bhagvat purana these are  Nitya  Avataras. Where lord can't be seen in his full glory. But from the recording's of the events of miracles  & teachings etc. Devotees understood these things. This type of avatara description is given in Bhagvat purana.I will update u with verses in sometime.